# What does the load-average used by parallel make represent?

Tags: build-process, build, makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU make on Windows, what exactly does the load-average value represent?

For example:

```
make -j --load-average=2.5
```

What does the 2.5 mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means that make will not start any new thread until the number of runnable processes, averaged over some period of time is below 2.5.

**Edit, following vines' remark**
a *runnable process*, in Unix parlance, is a process that is either waiting for CPU time or readily running.  Technically it is a process which is in TASK_RUNNING state.

However... this prompted me to re-read the original question, and note its "***on Windows***" part....
Whereby my original answer is, *loosely*, correct for GNU Make on Unix-like hosts, it is plain short of factual on Windows.  The discrepancy of behavior is due to the fact the the two operating systems provide very different metrics to describe their "current" CPU load.  Consequently Make's logic has to interpret these CPU load readings differently, to serve its --load-average feature.

The purpose of the `--load-average` parameter is to provide guidance to Make as to when it can start new threads; causing Make to share CPU resources with other applications (and within itself) more elegantly.
In Linux, the semantic of this parameter is very close to its name: new Make threads are allowed when the *load-average*, as reported by the kernel (I'm assuming this is the "one minute" load average, though it could be the five minutes one), is less than the parameter value.
In Windows, Make computes the load average from the weighed-average of the CPU Load (as reported by GetSystemTimes function) and the memory load (eg. from GlobalMemoryStatusEx function).

Comment: number of runnable processes? what's that?

Comment: Basically, on Unix, the load average indicates how many processes are waiting for their turn. The kernel can report this for the last minute, five minutes, or fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows - nothing, apparently.  This is a UNIX term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29

My copy of Cygwin reports zero load averages when I run the `uptime` command.  I don't think there is a quick way of calculating this on Windows; it was asked on the Cygwin mailing list in the past.

In other words: it's not implemented, so it's always zero.

Here's the implementation of `getloadavg`, directly from the GNU Make 3.81 sources:

```
# if !defined (LDAV_DONE) && (defined (__MSDOS__) || defined (WINDOWS32))
#  define LDAV_DONE

  /* A faithful emulation is going to have to be saved for a rainy day.  */
  for ( ; elem < nelem; elem++)
    {
      loadavg[elem] = 0.0;
    }
# endif  /* __MSDOS__ || WINDOWS32 */
```

I haven't checked on newer versions of GNU make but I doubt it's changed.